# How can I get an int/double for most significant and less significant byte?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, garmin

I get those bytes from a speed sensor:

```
 byte[] array = new byte[2];

 array[0] = response.getDataPayload()[6]; 
 array[1] = response.getDataPayload()[7];
```

First is the MSB (Most significant byte) and the second one LSB (Less significant byte). I know this because that's what it sais in the documentation...

How can I transform the two variables into an int/double? (in c#)

Comment: Use Convert.ToInt32 method - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hk2thbx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Look at the BitConverter class

Comment: `int result = (((int)array[0]) << 8) | array[1];` Should do the trick. I forgot the Or (`|`) the first time around.

Answer (score 4):

There is a built-in class called [BitConverter](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.bitconverter%2528v%3Dvs.110%2529.aspx&ei=IJk-Ve2-HuO0sATgsoHYDw&usg=AFQjCNFZm-vgDsN8fHTOcMWxN013Dk83fw&sig2=Kom_bs5fvcoCcMaKgfQXNw) that does just that:

```
    byte[] array = new byte[2];

     array[0] = response.getDataPayload()[7]; 
     array[1] = response.getDataPayload()[6];

//or, you could do:
     array[0] = response.getDataPayload()[6];
     array[1] = response.getDataPayLoad()[7];
     Array.Reverse(array);
//end-or

    short myVar = BitConverter.ToInt16(array, 0);

    int myInt = (int)myVar;
    double myDouble = (double)myVar;
```

Since 2 bytes is a short (16 bit integer) thats what you get out of the sensor. You can then cast it to a full 32-bit integer or a double if you want.

The bytes are swapped for endianness.

Comment: Better swap the way you fill in the array, `BitConverter` is little-endian.

Comment: Just a matter of taste, but to me `int myInt = (int)myVar; double myDouble = (double)myVar;` looks overly explicit. I would use either `int myInt = myVar; double myDouble = myVar;`, or `var myInt = (int)myVar; var myDouble = (double)myVar;`. The resulting bytecode is the same, of course.

Comment: It is verbose and personally I wouldn't do it in practice but it shows that the variables can be changed to the other type. The casts are 100% not required here, but would be when using a type that can't be implicitly converted, like a double to a float.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert all bytes as positive number try this one:

```
int value = array[1]*256 + array[0];
```

Comment: Also close but wrong

Comment: Hint, 0x0100 is not 255

Comment: @BenVoigt to be very pedantic AdamF suggested to "try" code, and never claimed this is correct solution :)